# Literal ellipsis in type annotations

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

If I use this code with MyPy:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def mul3(x: T) -> T:  
    return 3 * x

for x in [4, 6, 3.4]:
    print(f"{x=}, {mul3(x)=}")
```

I get the error:

```
example.py:7: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")
example.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for * ("int" and "T")
```

I found out that it works if I use this code:

```
T = TypeVar("T", int, float)
```

I understand that it takes `T` as the type of the argument and `int` as the type of the resualt in the first code example. I also understand that they are different and they should be the same. What I don't understand is why the argument cannot be inferred as type `int`. This would seem more natural and logical to me, so I think I got something wrong.

Comment: Without the constraint, MyPy can't be sure that `3 * x` has the same type as `x`. The fact that you're only passing integers and floats is irrelevant, the definition itself is unsound.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with literal ellipses. There are no ellipses anywhere here.

Comment: you are right, sorry I used it in a context with literal ellipses and what you see is just an extract. I apologize for the misleading title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the only requirement for `x` is that its type should allow the `3 * x` operation. We can express that by defining a `typing.Protocol`:

```py
from typing import Literal, Protocol, Self, TypeVar


class SupportsMultiplicationBy3(Protocol):
    def __rmul__(self, __value: Literal[3]) -> Self:
        ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=SupportsMultiplicationBy3)


def mul3(x: T) -> T:
    return 3 * x


for x in [4, 6, 3.4]:
    print(f"{x=}, {mul3(x)=}")
```

---

Defining the `TypeVar` as either `int` or `float` works, since both `int`s and `float`s can multiply the `3` literal.

Comment: Omg, I'd never think to define something which can be multiplied at 3... It'd probably go with `int` or `float` for `__value` type, but this is smart!